# Fix DocuSign SOAP API Error on TLS Version

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign SOAP APIs in .net web app to send out envelopes for e-signature. This was working fine, I last sent envelopes on Feb. 4th. 
But today I began getting a message that I needed to update to TLS 1.2.
The error is as below:
TLS_Invalid_Version TLSv1.2 is required. Currently using TLSv1

How do I fix that? I am running Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 with .net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the security problems of TLS 1.0 and below, those standards are no longer supported. End of support for those standards was announced about 6 months ago by DocuSign on the monthly release notes.

You'll need to update your stack to support TLS 1.1 (or better, 1.2). TLS 1.1 is supported. TLS 1.0 and below is no longer supported. I'm sorry this was a surprise for you.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.7 and still seeing the same error.

Comment: This [WIndows doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) may be of help. You need to check that your application, the SOAP library, and the Windows OS are net setting an explicit TLS version. The article also says that v 4.7.1 is needed if you have a WCF app. You also need to check any front end gateways if they act as the end point for the TLS connection.